# NuxtJS static generated page setup for nginx?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I finally finish my project and ready to deploy. I generate my html files with `yarn generate` then point my nginx config to the /dist file. But when I visit the site, it looks like the JS is not getting loaded. Is there a config that I'm missing?

Console.log shows about 6 of this. (I think that's the number of my components that is not being loaded)
`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

btw, only my footer and navbar component is visible on the page, probably because there's no js to it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could read these guidelines before asking a new question. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've been searching this site and google for about 2 hours already and haven't found a good answer.

Comment: It's not just about searching before asking a question, it's also about helping us help you. Did you use `vue-cli`? What is `yarn generate`? Did you check browser devtools network panel? If yes, what is the **Status** for js files? Are there any requests for **js** files? What are the paths to those **js** files?

Comment: Maybe you can check vue docs about [Deployment](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#general-guidelines)

Comment: The console log error suggests its a 404 and its seeing the html.. so check for 404s then check the nginx config is right